# Where does log stash saves my data?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am wondering where log-stash saves my data, I want to delete all the existing data because I made a mistake when I am uploading, I tried to delete all the indices and cleared the cache but my data is still present on the kibana. I checked my elasticsearch.yml file for the location of the data and I manually delete all the indices but my data is still on the kibana. Can any one helps me out on deleting the existing data?

Thanks in advance. This is my elastic search config file :

```
cluster.name: elastic search
network.host: ****
node.name: "mole"
node.data: true
node.master: true
path.data: /opt/data/elasticsearch/
path.work: /opt/data/elasticsearch/
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide your configuration files for both logstash and elasticsearch in order for anyone to help you.

Comment: This is my elastic search config file : cluster.name: elastic search
network.host: ****
node.name: "mole"
node.data: true
node.master: true
path.data: /opt/data/elasticsearch/
path.work: /opt/data/elasticsearch/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete index API allows to delete an existing index.

```
$ curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/'
```

Assuming you running elasticsearch at 9200 port.
The above example deletes an index called twitter. Specifying an index, alias or wildcard expression is required.

The delete index API can also be applied to more than one index, or on all indices (be careful!) by using

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'
```

In order to disable allowing to delete indices via wildcards or _all, set action.destructive_requires_name setting in the config to true. This setting can also be changed via the cluster update settings api.

[Reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html)

Comment: Vova Lando, hello thanks for the response. I have tried the same thing but the data is still present on my kibana dashboard,  I want to clear all the data , then i can run execute my scripts to get the new data.

Comment: It worked for me, the second line: "curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'"
Are you sure that you running your elasticsearch on port 9200? Check elasticsearch config at /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: Vova Lando, yes I am pretty sure $ curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/antivirus*/
{"acknowledged":true} but my data is still present on the kibana.